# FileNotFound Error when exiting VENV after using AWS SAM CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-venv, aws-sam

I recently uninstalled python 3.10.x to put on 3.9.x as my company literally uses 3.9.x everywhere and 3.10.x was causing issues for me. After doing that I created a `hello_world` from sam cli and also made a `VENV` and did the following commands.

**1st set of commands**

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools &&
pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade (I have also tried with --no-cache-dir)
```

After everything was installed I ran the following commands to get the sam up and running locally
**2nd set of commands**

```
sam build
sam local start-api
```

When I run all of the commands 1st time they work fine, but as soon as I `ctrl+c` to close the local service I get 1 of the 2 errors. It can be either `config_dir` another time it can be `project_files` and I do not have a clue what is causing this. I've tried a number of re-creations of venv and nothing changes. Also after I get the error I can no longer use the same instance of my terminal and I have to start a new instance inside `VSCode`. I'm using `Ubuntu WSL` on a Windows Machine.

**1st**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/bin/sam", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1257, in invoke
    sub_ctx = cmd.make_context(cmd_name, args, parent=ctx)
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 700, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1048, in parse_args
    value, args = param.handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1630, in handle_parse_result
    value = invoke_param_callback(self.callback, ctx, self, value)
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 123, in invoke_param_callback
    return callback(ctx, param, value)
  File "/mnt/c/Main Storage/_GitHub Repos/service-translation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/samcli/cli/cli_config_file.py", line 133, in configuration_callback
    config_dir = getattr(ctx, "samconfig_dir", None) or os.getcwd()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**2nd**

```
CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/bin/sam", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 153, in wrapped
    project_type = ProjectTypes.CDK.value if is_cdk_project(template_dict) else ProjectTypes.CFN.value
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/samcli/lib/iac/cdk/utils.py", line 27, in is_cdk_project
    _relevant_cdk_files_are_present(),
  File "/mnt/c/Users/marti/OneDrive/Desktop/AWS Lambda Dockerfile/powertools-quickstart/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/samcli/lib/iac/cdk/utils.py", line 73, in _relevant_cdk_files_are_present
    project_files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**IMPORTANT:**
If you want to re-create the with same steps as I did here's exactly what I've done.

```
sam init --runtime python3.9 --dependency-manager pip --app-template hello-world --name powertools-quickstart

cd powertools-quickstart

python3.9 -m venv venv
```

Execute the 1st set of commands I've added to this post above.

Execute the 2nd set of command I've added to this post above.